# Towing 2020 Hyundai Venue

Tags: towing

Need to tow my 2020 Hyundai Venue home 1200 miles at highway speeds, behind a 36’ RV. We have a trailer you put the 2 front tires on that we have towed a Chevy Sonic with.

Uhaul says yes you can use this type of towing. Others say no you flat tow it. I really need to know soon! Please help

Comment: Your owners manual will tell you how to tow (or how **not** to tow) the vehicle.

Comment: BTW - Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!